# How to save a request body?

Tags: javascript, post, promise, fetch

I'm learning JS, but i can't find how to save a request body after my fetch POST. Using only JS

```
async function connectUser () {
    const log = document.querySelector("#formulaireConnexion")
    log.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
        event.preventDefault()

        const user = {
            email: event.target.querySelector("[name=mail]").value,
            password: event.target.querySelector("[name=mdp]").value
        }

        const objectUser = JSON.stringify(user)


        fetch("http://localhost:5678/api/users/login", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {"Content-Type" : "application/json"},
            body: objectUser
        }).then(r => r.json())
        .then(body => console.log(body))
    })
}

connectUser()
```

Comment: Where and why do you want to save the request body? On the server or on the local machine? Do you mean the response body?

Comment: Are you just trying to use `body`? See [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](/q/14220321/4642212).

Comment: I need to save the body request as var on the local machine.
i need it to know if user exist or not, then log with the request body token

Comment: The last comment doesn't make sense. What does it mean to _"save the body request as var on the local machine"_? Are you sure you don't mean the response body? You have the request body in `objectUser`.

Comment: Sorry, the request of my fetch is an "ID user" + "token".
 i get them with my "console.log(body)"
but i dont know how to get them in a const outside the function
Sorry, didn't write English for a long time..

Comment: You can't store the response in a const outside the function. The const is created before the function is evaluated. You can store it in a variable, but you'll have to pay attention to the timing. Read the duplicate.

Answer (score -2):

You can save it in session or localstoreAge.
Like that
`const objectUser = sessionStorage.setItem(”saveit”,JSON.stringify(user));`

You can then use it like

`SessionStorage.getItem(”saveit”);`